# Visualization / Transforms with rosbridge and erratic

Tags: ros, visualization, erratic, rosbridge, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to create a website that displays the current progress of a robot (in this case erratic) running SLAM. With rosbridge I've been able to set up the subscriptions that I need, I think and I can draw all of the data in a similar way that rviz does.

The trouble is that each topic I've subscribed to has a lot of fields and I'm not sure how to get the transforms from each frame to line up when visualizing the slam map, the senses obstacles and the robot.

The topics of interest are:

```
/move_base_node/local_costmap/robot_footprint
/move_base_node/local_costmap/inflated_obstacles
/map
```

Obviously it makes sense that the topics under /move_base_node/local_costmap are in the same frame, but obviously /map is not.

Do I need to use tf to accomplish this? I couldn't find a tutorial for this kind of thing.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41587/visualization-/-transforms-with-rosbridge-and-erratic/) by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 549 on 2012-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) on 2012-08-22**:
[This](http://answers.ros.org/question/41760/coordinate-frame-transforms-odom-to-map/) was my solution in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you need `tf`.

In the `Header` of each topic there is a `frame_id`, naming the frame of reference for each message. This command should show the origins of each frame (assuming they are being published correctly somewhere).

```
$ rosrun tf tf_monitor
```

Rviz should be able to display your data in some appropriate frame of reference (probably `/map`).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0